# BUG : Mi boton personalizado de customtkinter tiene un BUG

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8, bug

Estoy intentando crear un modulo de **python** para agregar funciones extras al modulo de **customtkinter** y mi boton tiene un pequeño **bug visual**; al darle click todo funciona, pero si le das *click muy rapido* se ve como si se mesclaran los estados

El codigo del boton es este:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter.constants import *
relambda = lambda f, *a,**b: lambda *c,**d: f(*a,**b)

class CTkButton2(ctk.CTkFrame):
   def __init__(self, master,
      #***** BORRADO LO INNECESARIO
      border_width: int = 2,
      bg_color = "transparent",
      fg_color = None,
      border_color = None,
      hover_color = None,
      border_hover_color = None,
      text_color = None,
      text_color_disabled = None,

      text = "CTkButton",
      **kwargs          
   ):
      #** INICIO
      #? GUARDAR LOS TEMAS POR DEFECTO
      tema_fg_color = ctk.ThemeManager.theme["CTkButton"]["fg_color"]
      tema_text_color = ctk.ThemeManager.theme["CTkButton"]["text_color"]
      tema_hover_color = ctk.ThemeManager.theme["CTkButton"]["hover_color"]

      # EL FG_COLOR ES EL ENCARGADO DEL COLOR PRINCIPAL
      # EL HOVER_COLOR ES EL ENCARGADO DEL COLOR DE CLICK Y SELECCION
      if not fg_color: fg_color = tema_fg_color
      if not border_color: border_color = fg_color
      if not hover_color : hover_color = tema_hover_color
      if not border_hover_color : border_hover_color = hover_color
      if not text_color: text_color = ("black", tema_text_color[0])

      # # ESTABLECER LOS TEMAS PERSONALIZADOS
      self.__fg_color     = fg_color
      self.__border_color = border_color
      self.__hover_color  = hover_color
      self.__border_hover_color = border_hover_color
      self.__text_color   = text_color

      self._activate = False

      #? INICIAR EL BOTON
      self._BUILDING = True
      super(CTkButton2, self).__init__(master=master)
      self.__button = ctk.CTkButton(
       self,
       border_width=border_width,
       bg_color=bg_color, 
       fg_color="transparent", 
       hover_color=hover_color, 
       border_color=border_color,
       text_color=text_color, 
       text_color_disabled=text_color_disabled, 
       text=text, 
       **kwargs
      )
      self.__button.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
  
      #*****  BORRADO LO INNECESARIO

      #* CONTROLAR LOS EVENTOS DEL BOTON
      self.__button.bind("<Enter>", relambda(self._change, 0))
      self.__button.bind("<Leave>", relambda(self._change, 1))
      self.__button.bind("<Button-1>", relambda(self._change, 2))
      self.__button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", relambda(self._change, 0))

      self._BUILDING = False
      return

   #* ESTA FUNCION MANEJA LOS EVENTOS PARA CAMBIAR LOS ESTILOS VISUALES   
   def _change(self, modo):
      if self.cget("state") == DISABLED:
         modo = 1

      if modo==0: # EVENTO <ENTER>
         fg_color, text_color, border_color, hover_color = \
            self.__fg_color, self.__text_color[1], self.__border_color, self.__hover_color
      elif modo==1: # EVENTO <LEAVE>
         fg_color, text_color, border_color, hover_color = \
            "transparent", self.__text_color[0], self.__border_color, self.__hover_color
      elif modo == 2:  # EVENTO <BUTTON-1>
         fg_color, text_color, border_color, hover_color = \
            self.__hover_color, self.__text_color[1], self.__border_hover_color, self.__hover_color

      if self._activate:
         ff = self.__hover_color
         tt = self.__text_color
         fg_color, text_color, border_color, hover_color = ff, tt, ff, ff

      self.__button.configure(fg_color=fg_color, text_color=text_color,
                 border_color=border_color, hover_color=hover_color)
      return   

   def destroy(self):
      if self.__button:
         self.__button.destroy()
      return super().destroy()

   def configure(self, require_redraw=False, **kwargs):
      return self.__button.configure(require_redraw, **kwargs)

   def cget(self, attribute_name: str):
      if self._BUILDING:
         return super().cget(attribute_name)
      else:
         return self.__button.cget(attribute_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = ctk.CTk()
  div_botones = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)
  div_botones.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=8, pady=8, ipadx=16, ipady=16)

  ctk.CTkButton(master=div_botones, text="Boton original").pack(side=LEFT, padx=16)
  CTkButton2(master=div_botones, text="Boton 2").pack(side=LEFT, padx=16)
  CTkButton2(master=div_botones, text="Boton 3", fg_color="red", hover_color="darkred").pack(side=LEFT, padx=16)

  root.mainloop()
```

LA parte donde se manejan los eventos es en el metodo **_change**

Aunque el bug es visual, me irrita no saber porque es asi y me agadaria que me ayudaran

**Si en algo ayuda estoy usando python 3.8.3 y las versiones mas recientes de los modulos TK**

[image: Imagen de referencia]